# Using APIOPS how to add named values into policies.xml

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, apim

I'm now working with
https://github.com/Azure/apiops
on a project to interact with an APIM resource.
This means any API that I need to work on goes through the apiops repository.
We have file(s) `configuration.<env>.yaml`
That contains something like:

```
apimServiceName: nameofapimresource
namedValues:
  - name: azureTenantNameId
    properties:
      value: "xxx"
  - name: azureEnvironmentId
    properties:
      value: "dev"
```

From the documentation, those variables are supposed to work and resolve using brackets. ex: `{{azureTenantNameId}}`
Still, if I apply it to a policy.xml it's not translated into any value.

How are we supposed to work with variables in apiops?

Btw, those variables work using brackets on a `Specifications.json` file